# Python object.__getattribute__ not behaving correctly after override

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongoengine

I'm trying to replicate mongoengine functionality that lets you define field objects that can be used like normal python objects in the code.
My idea is to create a `FieldHolder` class that contains the value and (de)serialization logic, and a `Document` object with overridden `__setattr__` and `__getattribute__` methods.

In my code draft, if I set `x.h` to some value, this value gets correctly assigned to `x.h._value`. When I get `x.h`, I correctly get `x.h._value`.

However, I would also like get `h` as a `FieldHolder` object and not as its value. I have tried using `object.__getattribute__` (inside `serialize` method), but I'm still getting `h._value` (`object.__getattribute__(self, 'h')` returns `abc`). What am I doing wrong? Thanks

```py
class FieldHolder:

    _value = None
    # Some serialization and deserialization methods


class Document(object):

    h = FieldHolder()

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        attr = getattr(self, key, None)
        if attr is not None and isinstance(attr, FieldHolder):
            attr._value = value
        else:
            super().__setattr__(key, value)

    def __getattribute__(self, key):
        val = super().__getattribute__(key)
        if isinstance(val, FieldHolder):
            return val._value
        else:
            return val

    def serialize(self):
        res = {}
        for name, value in vars(self).items():
            obj = object.__getattribute__(self, name)  # not working as expected
            if isinstance(obj, FieldHolder):
                res[name] = value
        return res


x = Document()
x.h = "abc"  # h._value is now "abc"
print(x.h)   # prints "abc"
s = x.serialize() # should return {'h': 'abc'} but returns {}
print(s)
```

Comment: Why does `serialize` need the `FieldHolder` instance, rather than simply letting `res['h'] = self.h`? If there is a difference, you probably want to make `FieldHolder` a descriptor, rather than overriding anything in `Document`.

Comment: The `_value` attribute is a class attribute, so doesn't show up in `vars(FieldHolder())`, only in `vars(FieldHolder)`, which is why it isn't showing up when you call `vars(self)`. You can fix that by having `_value` as an instance attribute on `FieldHolder`, i.e. in the constructor for `FieldHolder`, have `self._value = None`